# How to start RxJava development on Android?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

as I've already noticed: more and more developers use RxJava for Android development.

I want to learn it. Can you recommended some Project use RxJava?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that visiting **Fragmented podcast** parts about `RxJava` (I linked them below) would be a nice start of your `RxJava` Development:

- [The RxJava show with Dan Lew (Part 1)](http://fragmentedpodcast.com/episodes/3/)
- [The RxJava show with Dan Lew (Part 2)](http://fragmentedpodcast.com/episodes/4/)
- [Jake Wharton on Testing, SqlBrite, NotRxAndroid, RxJava and Much More](http://fragmentedpodcast.com/episodes/7/)

Why these sites? Click on the first link and you would find there not only a player as on normal podcast page, but also many recommended by authors resources which are also explained in podcast.

Many projects with `RxJava` you would find on `GitHub`. I would recommend you these:

- https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples
- https://github.com/jhusain/learnrxjava
- https://github.com/richardradics/RxAndroidBootstrap

Also take a look at GitHub page of [`RxJava`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) and [`RxAndroid`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid), Android specific bindings for `RxJava`.

Any question? Please free to ask.

Hope it helps

Comment: I've made a relatively simple project using RxJava. Maybe you will find it helpful. http://aetherna-dev.wix.com/portfolio#!Handling-background-work-on-Android/mthx1/5679d4e90cf2c2b7798eedee

Comment: I would check it, thanks